# Executing a shell script, printing output as it happens, and blocking until it's done?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script written in JS that gets executed in Node (not a website, not an electron app; just `node myscript.js` in a terminal.  Part of that script is executing a series of other (shell) scripts sequentially, and printing the output from those scripts as it happens.

I've tried two approaches:

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

for (const argItemin list) {
  console.log(execSync('myscript.bat ' + argItem, {encoding: 'utf-8'}));
}
```

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

for (const argItem in list) {
  const execution = exec('myscript.bat ' + argItem);
  execution.stdout.on('data', function (data) { console.log(data); });
}
```

The first approach executes and prints everything synchronously, but the output gets written after the each `myscript.bat` execution completes rather than as `myscript.bat` prints it out.

The second approach prints things as they happen, but because there's nothing blocking until each execution completes, the output is a jumbled mess.

How do I block on the child process of the second approach until the script has finished executing to get the best of both worlds?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I wanted

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

for (const argItemin list) {
  console.log(execSync('myscript.bat ' + argItem, {stdio: 'inherit'}));
}
```